# localStorage Issue -- onblur is not working on Mobile Device

Tags: javascript

I have created a form that is working perfectly on web browsers but it is not working on mobile devices. I am using localStorage to save some info from step one to step two in my forms. The way i am doing this is by using onblur function to each input element. For example on an email input I add onblur="storeData()" . The form is working perfectly on web browsers but on mobile devices it is not. I am not sure what might be the issue but I think that the onblur is not working on mobile devices. How can i replace the onblur ONLY for mobile devices? Please if you know provide the JS code to test it.

Thanks.

JS Code:

```
<script>
    function storeData() {
        var userEmail = document.querySelector("#UserName");
        var userPhoneNumber = document.querySelector("#PhoneNumber");
        var userName = document.querySelector("#FirstName");
        var userLastName = document.querySelector("#LastName");
        localStorage.setItem("mail", userEmail.value);
        localStorage.setItem("phone", userPhoneNumber.value);
        localStorage.setItem("name", userName.value);
        localStorage.setItem("lastName", userLastName.value);
    }

    function getData() {
        var userEmail = document.querySelector("#UserName");
        var userPhoneNumber = document.querySelector("#PhoneNumber");
        var userName = document.querySelector("#FirstName");
        var userLastName = document.querySelector("#LastName");
        userEmail.value = localStorage.getItem("mail");
        userPhoneNumber.value = localStorage.getItem("phone");
        userName.value = localStorage.getItem("name");
        userLastName.value = localStorage.getItem("lastName");
    }
</script>
```

Comment: Are you sure your mobile devices support localStorage and allow websites to store data on the device?

Comment: Thanks for your answer @ste2425 I have tested on a variety of mobiles including iPhone 6s (chrome app) but it is not working for some reason. On desktop is working perfectly. I am not sure that it does not accept onblur but that is what I am thinking for now.